# Form Sending Multiple Emails After Submission

Tags: php, forms, email

I have a PHP script that collects leads from my website, and I asked a few business owners to test it for me. The problem is that only one of them is saying they're getting like 100+ emails a day for each submission.

I've been through the code with a fine-tooth comb and can't see any potential problem. This is bit that sends the email:

```
if ($notify_name && $notify_email && $notify_subject && $notify_message) {
            $mailheaders = 'From: ' . $notify_name . "\r\n" .
            'Reply-To: ' . $notify_email . "\r\n" .
            'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
            mail($_POST['lead_email'],$notify_email,$notify_message,$mailheaders);
        }
```

And once the form gets sent, I use

`unset($_POST['notify_name']);`

or

`unset($notify_name);`

...and it doesn't matter whether I `unset` all the variables, or do them individually - this particular user is still getting 100-200 emails a day.

I've also tried checking for spam - setting a field that's hidden by CSS and if it comes through with a value I know it's spam and cancel.

Any ideas? Thanks much in advance!

Comment: If that page is refreshed the form will resubmit unless you explicitly tell it not to. I don't see that in the code you've provided.

Comment: have you tried logging throughout the page? that usually helps spot the problem...it helps in finding loops, errors, and to aknowledge what part of the code has actually been processed...

Comment: You've presented the one piece of code that seems to be working :)
If there is an error it's not there... probably in a loop surrounding these lines...

Comment: @JulioSoares: The only other parts of the script are outside the mail submission; it writes an entry to the DB and displays a message on the page, then exits.

Comment: can you show the part where you set $notify_email ?

Comment: hummm 
The other testers are not receiving anything?  or receivng a single emai? as they should?

Comment: @JulioSoares Yes, other users are getting the single email as intended. :? $notify_email is pulling from a WP Options setting the user saves when they install the plugin. I'm using: 

`$notify_email = (isset($xleads_setup['notify_lead_email']))?$xleads_setup['notify_lead_email']:false;`

Comment: So there is a problem in your code where the $notify_email variable is being set.
We can't help based on what you type about code.
We need to see code.
I looks like something in the loop where you read the e-mail adresses to chose where to send... but we need to see... the send mail is working and it is not magic. it won't rum unless it's being called.
So we need to see it... whatever... didi you also unset $xleads_setup['notify_lead_email'] after using it?

Comment: @JulioSoares I can't unset the Wordpress options entry (`$xleads_setup['notify_lead_email'] `), or the user will have to re-enter after each form submission. That setting is saved using the recommended Wordpress method, when the user saves the email in the plugin settings page, it submits to options.php and Wordpress handles it. Not sure if it helps, but it runs like this: The script that writes the form to the front end also includes the part that detects submissions - after submission, it checks if those variables are set and if so it sends - then it unsets the variables from the form.